# Backdrop-filter not working on Safari IOS

Tags: html, css, ios, mobile-safari

I'm working in a web portfolio and I implemented a dropdown menu for mobile views. This dropdown menu has a blur background made with backdrop-filter property. It works perfectly in all browsers for mobile except in Safari. I don't know what i'm doing wrong :c here is my style for the dropdow menu

```
/* Dropdown menu */
.dropdown_menu-dark {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  right: 2rem;
  top: 60px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}

.dropdown_menu-dark.open {
  height: 300px;
}

/* HERE IS WHERE I SET THE BACKDROP FILTER */
@supports ((-webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(15px)) or (backdrop-filter: blur(15px))) {
  .dropdown_menu-dark {
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
    backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
  }
```

There is how it sees in the Safari browser
[Example In Safari Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOnYV.png)

And Here is how it looks in other mobile browsers (or how should looks)
[Example Other Browsers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xcdn9.png)

If you can tell me where I'm going wrong or if there is an alternative solution to creating this blurred background style (other than putting a blurred background image) it would be a great help to me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am having the same issue. I created my own private web UI tool as an alternative to React with full enter and exit animations on every component. It works really well, but it seems that if my components are not immediately mounted/visible, then backdrop blurring will not work in Safari. This definitely is a mistake on Safari's part. This seriously needs to be fixed. Tons of people use these things.